# how to get only one occurance of a line in a file

Tags: shell

i have a file raw-vobs-config-spec where there are two lines

```
element /vob/ccm_tpl/repository/open_source/ciscossl_fom/4_1/... TPLBASE
element /vob/ccm_tpl/repository/open_source/ciscossl/1_0_2d_5_4/... VERSION_04
```

i have my code:

```
OLD_VERSION=`grep "ciscossl" raw-vobs-config-spec | cut -d " " -f2 | awk -F "/" '{ print $(NF-1)}'`
echo $OLD_VERSION
total_fields=`grep "ciscossl" raw-vobs-config-spec | cut -d " " -f2 | awk -F "/" '{ print NF }'`
echo $total_fields
#directory_path=`grep "ciscossl" raw-vobs-config-spec | cut -d " " -f2 | cut -d"/" -f1-"${total_fields}"`
#echo $directory_path
loc=`grep "ciscossl" raw-vobs-config-spec_new | cut -d " " -f2 | cut -d"/" -f1-6`
echo $loc
```

so it is printing o/p as

```
4_1 1_0_2d_5_4
8 8
/vob/ccm_tpl/repository/open_source/ciscossl_fom 
/vob/ccm_tpl/repository/open_source/ciscossl
```

but i need the output as

```
4_1
8
/vob/ccm_tpl/repository/open_source/ciscossl_fom
```

how can i get that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `read` without `while` loop to read just one line first and then process the read text using `awk`:

```
# read one line from input file
read _ line _ < raw-vobs-config-spec

# process the line with awk
echo "$line" | awk 'BEGIN{FS=OFS="/"} {print $(NF-1) ORS NF; NF-=2; print}'
```

**Output:**

```
4_1
8
/vob/ccm_tpl/repository/open_source/ciscossl_fom
```

Comment: i am passing two directories in my script-one is ciscossl and the other one is cisossl_fom...so i need two different output for different directories     4_1
8
/vob/ccm_tpl/repository/open_source/ciscossl_fom        for ciscossl and  1_0_2d_5_4                                                                                              8   /vob/ccm_tpl/repository/open_source/ciscossl     if i pass ciscossl...how can i get that

Comment: This output matches with the expected output you had in question. For adding additional requirements comments is the not the proper way. I suggest you open a new question and you will sure be helped.